# Bash get php versions available for apache

Tags: bash

I want to get a list of all versions of PHP that have the apache module installed.

This is my function :

```sh
availableVersions () {
    available_versions="";

    for php_version in `ls -d /etc/php/*/apache2`
    do
        available_versions="${available_versions}| ${php_version} ";
    done

    echo $available_versions;
}
```

The return of function is :

```sh
| /etc/php/7.0/apache2 | /etc/php/7.1/apache2 | /etc/php/7.2/apache2 | /etc/php/7.3/apache2 | /etc/php/7.4/apache2 | /etc/php/8.0/apache2
```

But what i want is :

```sh
| 7.0 | 7.1 | 7.2 | 7.3 | 7.4 | 8.0
```

Here is a solution that I have just found, but it will have to be improved.

```sh
availablesVersions () {
    available_versions="";

    for php_version in `ls -d /etc/php/*/apache2`
    do
        version="${php_version///etc/''}";
        version="${version///php/''}";
        version="${version///apache2/''}";
        version="${version////''}";

        available_versions="${available_versions}| ${version} ";
    done

    echo $available_versions;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Currently I am trying to use "Substring Match" to get the version.
For example : in the string "/etc/php/7.4/apache2" i watch to get just "7.4".

Comment: @sckraa Can you edit your question to include your attempt at using substring functions to extract the content you desire? Unless I’m missing something it doesn’t look like this is reflected in your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

availablesVersions () {
  ##: Just in case there are no files, the glob will not expand to something.
  shopt -s nullglob

  ##: Keep variables (array name, varname) local to the function.
  declare -a versions
  local output 

  versions=(/etc/php/*/apache2)   ##: Save the files in an array
  versions=("${versions[@]%/*}")  ##: Remove the last /
  versions=("${versions[@]##*/}") ##: Remove the first / longest match
  versions=("${versions[@]/#/ }") ##: Add trailing space
  versions=("${versions[@]/%/ }") ##: Add leading space
  output=$( IFS='|'; printf '|%s' "${versions[*]}" ) ##: Format output
  echo "${output% }" ##: Print the output without the trailing space.

  shopt -u nullglob ##: Disable nullglob.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `extglob` you can do this:

```sh
(
shopt -s extglob ## enable extended glob
versions=(/etc/php/*/apache2) ## Save the files in an array
IFS='|' ## set IFS to |
## print values after replacing unwanted part
printf '| %s ' "${versions[@]//@(\/etc\/php\/|\/apache2)}" 
)
```

**Output:**

```
| 7.0 | 7.1 | 7.2 | 7.3 | 7.4 | 8.0
```

PS: Using `( ... )` to run these commands in a sub-shell to avoid changing `IFS` for parent shell.